# Jqgrid row height changes on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid

Here is my colNames:

```
colNames: ['', '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-flag"></span>', 'NTPEP Number', 'Manufacturer', 'Product', 'Status','','Data', 'Actions'],
```

Here is my colModel:

```
 colModel: [{ name: 'tc_id', index: 'tc_id', align: 'left', hidden: true, resizable: false, key: true },
            { name: 'Flag', index: 'Flag', width:30,align: 'left', resizable: false, formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) { return "<div id= flag_" + rowObject[0] + " class='flag'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-flag'></span></div>" } },
                   { name: 'NTPEP_Number', index: 'NTPEP_Number', width: 150, align: 'left', resizable: false, formatter: fontColorFormat },
                   { name: 'Manufacturer', index: 'Manufacturer', width: 200, align: 'left', resizable: false },
                   { name: 'Product', index: 'Product', width: 150, align: 'left', resizable: false, formatter: fontColorFormat },
                   { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 80, align: 'left', resizable: false },
                   { name: 'Locked_Flag', index: 'Locked_Flag', width: 30, align: 'left', resizable: false,formatter:lockedFlag},

                  { name: 'Data', sortable: false, edittype: 'select', width: 70, align: 'left', sortable: false, formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) { return "<div id= action_" + rowObject[0] + " class='action'><div class='btn-group' id='actions'><div class='collapse navbar-collapse'><ul class='actions'><li class='dropdown'><a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle grid-icon' data-toggle='dropdown'></a><ul class='dropdown-menu'><li><a href='#'>Product</a></li><li><a href='#'>Test</a></li></ul></li></ul></div></div><div class='clear'></div></div>"; }, resizable: false },
                   { name: 'Actions', index: 'Actions', sortable: false, edittype: 'select', width: 85, align: 'left', sortable: false, formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) { return "<div id= action1_" + rowObject[0] + " class='action1'><div class='btn-group' id='actions'><div class='collapse navbar-collapse'><ul class='actions'><li class='dropdown'><a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle grid-icon' data-toggle='dropdown'></a><ul class='dropdown-menu'><li><a href='#'>Product</a></li><li><a href='#'>Test</a></li></ul></li></ul></div></div><div class='clear'></div></div>"; }, resizable: false }],

        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [2, 10, 20, 50],   // page size dropdown
        pager: jQuery('#pager_Alerts'),
        pgbuttons: true,            
        viewrecords: true,          
        pagerpos: 'right',
        recordpos: 'left',
        shrinkToFit: false,
        sortorder: "asc",
        sortname: "tc_id",
        loadtext: "Loading",
        width: 795,
       height: "100%",
        hoverrows: false,
        onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {}
```

In Chrome,when i move the mouse over rows,row height increase automatically like as follow.
[image]

***This is not desired behavior:***

While in IE,it works fine ,just like normal jqgrid row.
[image]

Kindly tell me,what is the problem?Is it **css** problem or i am missing some property?